# Export mutliple query output into one excel sheet using Redshift and SQL Developer

Tags: csv, oracle-sql-developer, excel, redshift

I am connected to Redshift from SQL Developer 19.2.1.
I have a requirement to export multiple query output into a single excel sheet, one query output should be in one Tab. Please advise on how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export the data from Redshift to excel you can use some software like Talend Open Integration or export directly to CSV with the UNLOAD functionality that Redshift has.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html